# Global step does not start at 0

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have an RNN using a MonitoredTrainingSession for distributed computation. I’m using global_step to identify which batch of input data each worker should take.

I have defined the tensor before creating the session

```
global_step_tensor = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.int32, trainable=False, name=‘global_step’)
...
minimise = optimiser.minimize(loss, name=‘adam_opt’, global_step=‘global_step’)
with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(...) as sess:
    graph=tf.get_default_graph()
    curr_step=sess.run(global_step_tensor)
    print(curr_step) #gives 366
```

I thought the variable is only incremented on evaluation of the optimiser? Why does it start on 366?

**Edit** My cluster is defined as one ps and two workers. Currently, whilst I test, all three are running on the same host through different ports.

Comment: If you have a saved checkpoint, all variables will be loaded from that checkpoint, including global_step. This is done to allow graceful recovery if your machine crashes in the middle of a long training session. Perhaps you previously ran a training session which saved a checkpoint at that step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, [`MonitoredTrainingSession`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/MonitoredTrainingSession) have several default arguments that make checkpoints automatically:

> `save_checkpoint_secs`: The frequency, in seconds, that a checkpoint is
>   saved using a default checkpoint saver. If save_checkpoint_secs is set
>   to None, then the default checkpoint saver isn't used.
>
> `save_summaries_steps`: The frequency, in number of global steps, that
>   the summaries are written to disk using a default summary saver. If
>   both save_summaries_steps and save_summaries_secs are set to None,
>   then the default summary saver isn't used. Default 100.
>
> `save_summaries_secs`: The frequency, in secs, that the summaries are
>   written to disk using a default summary saver. If both
>   save_summaries_steps and save_summaries_secs are set to None, then the
>   default summary saver isn't used. Default not enabled.

Maybe that's why your current batch is not `0` anymore.